# Weird unserializing of json array in Spring controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring, serialization

I'm using Spring 3.1.1 with an annotated controller-method looking like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/my/url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Response<SomeModel>
doStuff(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam List<String> ids)
```

I post to this with jQuery:

```
$.post('/my/url', 
            {ids: JSON.stringify($ids.get())},
            function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }, 'json');
```

If I look at the traffic from the browser, it seems ok:

```
ids:["770409362","771999003","775080915","775119397","775831772"]
```

But the Java `List<String>`I get has added extra [ and ] to the first and last element:

```
[["770409362", "771999003", "775080915", "775119397", "775831772"]]
```

and also the quotes are remaining.

I have no idea how to get rid of it. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Seconds after posting found the join() method:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

So I did

```
{ids: $ids.get().join()}
```

which gave me

```
ids:133753573,1198385893,1513233125,12117275
```

instead which worked. Doesn't seem to be the right way to do this however. Would really like some kind of best-practice Spring/jQuery approach…?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@RequestBody List<String> ids` instead of `@RequestParam List<String> ids`  on the server side.

Comment: I tried that, but I had the same problem. It seemed they just needed it without the quotes and array-notation.